# Ordering on a lambda in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a scenario where I fetch  business groups through a lambda and collect data to be sent as a json.

The code is here:

```
 def get_business_with_details
  businesses = self.business_groups
  binding.pry
  businesses.collect do |business|
    {
      name: business.actor.name,
      id: business.access_key,
      is_business_admin: business.is_admin_user(self.id)
    }
  end
end
```

The lambda code for business groups is here:

```
 class User
  has_many :business_groups, lambda { |user| where ["(groups.group_type 
  = 7 )"] }, through: :group_members, source: :group
 end
```

I need to order the data on the name of business actor i.e `business.actor.name`

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd suggest to add `order` to your `has_many :business_groups` relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First iterate over each **businesses** and create array of hashes.
- Then sort the array of hash with particular key value i.e. **name** key.
- Then convert sorted array of hash into json.

The final code would look like this

```
def get_business_with_details
    businesses = self.business_groups.includes(:actor)
    businesses = businesses.collect do |business|
        {
        'name' => business.actor.name,
        'id' => business.access_key,
        'is_business_admin' => business.is_admin_user(self.id)
        }
    end
    businesses = businesses.sort_by { |hsh| hsh['name'] }
    businesses.to_json #final return value i.e. json converted and sorted by name
end
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: you should do `self.business_groups.includes(:actor)`, it avoids the n+1 query

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_business_with_details
  self.business_groups.
       joins(:actor).
       order('actor.name').
       map do |business|
    %w[name id is_business_admin].zip(
      business.actor.name, business.access_key, business.is_admin_user(self.id)
    ).to_h
  end.to_json
end
```